# Rename a group of image files

Tags: linux, windows, centos

How would I go about renaming a group of files to sequential numbers? ie.

```
IMG_001.png
IMG_002.png
IMG_312.png
```

to

```
1.png
2.png
3.png
```

I need to do this with hundreds of files, as there are overlaps in the names of image files I've taken on the same date.

Edit: I am storing these on a NAS server, therefore, I am able to do this over the command line as well.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps:

```
#!/bin/sh
mkdir tmp
I=1
for f in *.png; do
   mv $f tmp/$I.png
   I=$(($I+1))
done
mv tmp/*.png .
rmdir tmp
```

I used a 'tmp' folder to avoid existing file(s) "{some-number}.png" being accidentally overwritten.

Answer (score 0):

just from terminal:

```
count=1;for x in *.png;do mv $x $count.png;count=$((count+1)); done
```